# Store data in a non reactive way

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to store the old value of an input field so that I can check whether the value has changed or not. However, I'm rendering multiple inputs based on a property and can not determine the original value after the input has changed. So I tried using `data-`attributes. But they will unfortunately also change there values. How can I achieve this.

```
<input v-for="item in items" 
       :value="item.value" 
       :data-originalValue="item.value" <!-- this shall not change -->
/>
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want. Perhaps the simplest is to add properties to the instance directly and they won't be reactive.

```
created() {
    this.originalValues = this.items.map(item => item.value);
}
```

If you need to track changes to `items`, then you can use a watcher

```
watch: {
    items: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(newValue) {
           this.originalValues = this.newValue.map(item => item.value);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also handle the `input` events explicitly

```
<input
    v-for="item in items"
    :value="item.value"
    @input="onInput(item, $event)"
/>
```

And then in the handler

```
methods: {
    onInput(item, event) {
       // item is the item that changed
       // event.target.value is the new value
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't modify the instance directly, seems like asking for trouble. A watcher would be much better. If you just need to do something when they change, a watcher is just what you need. You can add a second argument to the handler that will be the old value and do whatever comparison you need.